# How to read a response from a single common ajax function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I wrote a single common ajax function. Instead of writing multiple times. So I just sending post data and URL to my common function. Till here everything is fine and I'm getting a response too. But I'm getting trouble to read that response.

```
function _ajax_post(someData,URL)
            {
                var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',                    
                    data: someData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: URL
                });

                ajaxCall.done(function(data) {
                    console.log("A good programmer looks both ways before crossing a one-way street :) ");
                });

                ajaxCall.fail(function(data) {
                    console.log(" Design is choosing how you will fail.");
                });

                ajaxCall.always(function() {
                    console.log("Truth can only be found in one place: the code.");
                });

                return ajaxCall;
            }
```

Here I calling like

```
$('#btnOutput').on('click', function () {
                   var str = $("#out").text();
                   var r = _ajax_post({"data":str},url+"roles/vu_menus/tets");
                   console.log(r);                          
                });
```

In my console.log() I'm getting a response like

```
{readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort: ƒ (a)
always: ƒ ()
complete: ƒ ()
done: ƒ ()
error: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ (a)
overrideMimeType: ƒ (a)
pipe: ƒ ()
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ (a)
readyState: 4
responseJSON: {data: "[{"text":"Home","href":"http://home.com","icon":"f…"fas fa-filter","target":"_self","title":""}]}]}]"}
responseText: "{"data":"[{\"text\":\"Home\",\"href\":\"http:\/\/home.com\",\"icon\":\"fas fa-home\",\"target\":\"_top\",\"title\":\"My Home\"},{\"text\":\"Opcion2\",\"href\":\"\",\"icon\":\"fas fa-chart-bar\",\"target\":\"_self\",\"title\":\"\"},{\"text\":\"Opcion3\",\"href\":\"\",\"icon\":\"fas fa-bell\",\"target\":\"_self\",\"title\":\"\"},{\"text\":\"Opcion4\",\"href\":\"\",\"icon\":\"fas fa-crop\",\"target\":\"_self\",\"title\":\"\"},{\"text\":\"Opcion5\",\"href\":\"\",\"icon\":\"fas fa-flask\",\"target\":\"_self\",\"title\":\"\"},{\"text\":\"Opcion6\",\"href\":\"\",\"icon\":\"fas fa-map-marker\",\"target\":\"_self\",\"title\":\"\"},{\"text\":\"Opcion7\",\"href\":\"\",\"icon\":\"fas fa-search\",\"target\":\"_self\",\"title\":\"\",\"children\":[{\"text\":\"Opcion7-1\",\"href\":\"\",\"icon\":\"fas fa-plug\",\"target\":\"_self\",\"title\":\"\",\"children\":[{\"text\":\"Opcion7-1-1\",\"href\":\"\",\"icon\":\"fas fa-filter\",\"target\":\"_self\",\"title\":\"\"}]}]}]"}"
setRequestHeader: ƒ (a,b)
state: ƒ ()
status: 200
statusCode: ƒ (a)
statusText: "OK"
success: ƒ ()
then: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
```

Now, How can I get **responseText** value?

Comment: You're returning the promise from the AJAX call. As such, use `done()` or `then()` to perform some logic once the call completes, or you could pass in a callback function to `_ajax_post()` which you can call from the `done()` you define in there.

Comment: You also might be interested in: https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: I tried that and I'm getting undefined @freedomn-m

Comment: try using 'html' dataType

Comment: Can you show me an example @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I did @AswinKumar and I'm getting same response

Comment: `ajaxCall.done(function(data) { console.log(data); })`  or `r.done(function(data) { console.log(data); })` depending on where you want it.

Comment: @Siddharthaesunuri do you want to get the responseText in the `_ajax_post` wrapper or in the click event handler?

Comment: Yes! I want to read responseText value at click event handler @freedomn-m

Comment: Actually, I didn't get you @RoryMcCrossan. How can I setup callback function here

Comment: put,
`r.success(function(){
// put debugger and find the response text here
})`
after ajax post function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your ajax wrapper returns the ajax promise, you can use that in your click event handler in exactly the same way as you do in the wrapper:

```
function _ajax_post(someData,URL)
{
    var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',                    
                data: someData,
                dataType: 'json',
                url: URL
    });


    ajaxCall.done(function(data) {
        console.log("global done");
    });

    return ajaxCall;
}

$('#btnOutput').on('click', function () {
   var str = $("#out").text();
   var r = _ajax_post({"data":str}, url+"roles/vu_menus/tets");

   // at this point, r is the ajax promise, so can use .done / .fail etc

   r.done(function(data) { 
     console.log(data); 
   });

});
```